# Label still taking up space when absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a javascript validation plugin which is used in too many places to replace. It inserts a label after the input it is validating. Current unvalidated mark up & image below:

Would have loved to show images but I guess I can't yet.

```
<div id="gender-select">
    <label id="gender">Gender</label>
        <input class="male required radioBtn gender-hide" type="radio" name="gender" value="1" id="male">
        <label for="male"></label>
        <input class="female required radioBtn gender-hide" type="radio" name="gender" value="2" id="female">
        <label for="female"></label>
</div>
```

This is the code after the validation is run and the input for gender is invalid.

```
<div id="gender-select">
    <label id="gender">Gender</label>
       <input class="male required radioBtn gender-hide error" type="radio" name="gender" value="1" id="male">
       <label for="gender" generated="true" class="error">Mandatory</label>
       <label for="male"></label>
       <input class="female required radioBtn gender-hide error" type="radio" name="gender" value="2" id="female">
       <label for="female"></label>
</div>
```

Current CSS

```
#join-page #form-content input[type="radio"] {
position: absolute;
left: -8000px;
}

#join-page #form-content input {
background: #f4f4f4;
height: 40px;
border: none;
padding: 0 2%;
width: 100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
font-size: 16px;
color: #a2a2a2;
}

#join-page #form-content input[type="radio"] + label {
background: url('/App_Presentation/responsive/OpinionMilesClub/img/omc-genderRadio.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 30px;
}

#join-page #form-content label.error[for="gender"] {
position: absolute;
top: -11px;
left: 0px;
}

#join-page #form-content input[type="radio"] + label[for="female"] {
margin-left: -4px;
background: url('/App_Presentation/responsive/OpinionMilesClub/img/omc-genderRadio.png') 31px 0px;
}
```

I don't understand why the label still takes up space? Anyone have any idea...

Comment: Do you want the space and label to disappear or do you just want the label to disappear?

Comment: I just want the label to act like any other element when it's absolutely positioned. When it appears it's moving the label below it. It shouldn't effect it at all.

Comment: Please include your javascript code